# What is the round object given to Philippe by Papa Rudy?

Tags: props, the-walk

What is the roundish object given to Philippe by Papa Rudy in *The Walk* (2015)?
It appears to bear some resemblance to a tape measure.

And what is the significance of the scene near the end when Jeff shows he has the object in question in his pocket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Papa Rudy grandfather's ANTIQUE LEATHER TAPE MEASURE.

> Emotion almost overtaking Papa Rudy, he digs into a nearby desk drawer
>   and gently removes an **ANTIQUE LEATHER TAPE MEASURE** -- hand-stitched,
>   circa 1900's.
>
> PAPA RUDY: **"It was my grandfather's. You'll need this."**
>
> Petit gently holds the beautiful tape measure as if it was made of
>   glass.

Petit gave it to Jeff when he need to measure where to place cavallettis.

> PETIT: "Here, lay this out. We need to measure where to place the
>   cavallettis."
>
> Petit hands Jeff the PAPA RUDY MEASURING TAPES.
>
> PETIT: "Use this. But whatever you do..."
>
> Jeff stops him.
>
> JEFF: **"I guard with life..."**
>
> Petit smiles as Jeff runs out the tape out alongside the
>   clothesline...

Comment: @gandalf3 me too. so yesterday I searched for an answer on web, found the movie script and share it on stackexchange! :)